# Access tez job history

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hadoop2, tez, bigdata

I want to get job information from the job history server for the tez execution engine.

Currently all map reduce jobs are reflected on the job history server but not the tez ones.

Job history is using some kind of logs to get all the information. Where can I find those logs? If the information is not available on the job history server I can parse those logs to get the information I need.

I have already tried parsing pig-tez cmd logs. Parsing that does not contain enough information and does not work for hive on tez.

Comment: What have you done so far? post your code

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, do you realize that tez actually does the work in map jobs?

Comment: Thank you Dennis and Burhanuddin. Actually i wanted execution history information for hive jobs executed with tez as execution engine.I found all the dag information on application timeline server that i needed . Thanks for replying.